# why is my sub-query when ran independently is not giving output

Tags: sql, t-sql, databricks

I was trying to find the second highest salary but when I run the below query:

```
select EmpID, Empsal, dense_rank() over (order by Empsal desc) r
from Employee_1 ;
```

is throwing an error.

When I re-write the same in other way, it is working very fine.

```
select *
from
  (select EmpID, Empsal, dense_rank() over (order by Empsal desc) r
   from Employee_1)
where r = 2;
```

Can anyone help me in understanding this?

Comment: "is throwing error." -- What error?

Answer (score 0):

The `FROM` and `WHERE` clauses are evaluated before the `SELECT` one. You can see this in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), paragraph "Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement".

In your first query, you assign the alias `r` in the `SELECT`, but you use it in the `WHERE` when it has not been already created, which throws an error (by the way, next time, please include WHAT error you are getting).

In the second query, the derived table (ie the parenthesis, the subquery) is part of the `FROM` clause, which is processed before the `WHERE`, so no error is thrown.

Comment: The OP must have edited the question after your answer because the first query does not have a WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `offset` and `fetch next`:

```
select EmpID, Empsal
from Employee_1
order by Empsal desc
offset 1 rows
fetch next 1 rows only;
```